# Dialog Box with Views in it - CakePHP

Tags: jquery, html, cakephp, hyperlink, dialog

I have a simple dialog box that pops up when I hit a sample link button on my page.  What I want to do is change the onclick jquery function from the link to one of my buttons in my table.  The buttons currently direct the web browser to a new page, but I want them to open the dailog box with thier corresponding view file in it.  I am using CakePHP 2.x.
I looked into using href but Im not sure how to go about that.

Here is the code for my index.ctp file where the buttons are located.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/themes/start/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />

<a href="#">link</a>   <!-- this is to test if the dialog box works -->
<div id="dialog"></div>

<script>
var p = '<p>test test test test test test</p>';
$('#viewButton').click(function()
{
//  $(location).attr('href', 'view.ctp');  // not sure if this line of code is on the right track or not
    $(p).dialog(
    {
        width: 400,
        height: 400,
        modal: true,
        resizable: true,
        buttons:{
            OK: function(){
                $(this).dialog("close");}}
    });
})
</script>

<p><marquee><u>Local Clocks</u></marquee></p>

<table>
    <thead><tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
    </tr></thead>
<tbody>

<?php 
foreach($localClocks as $LocalClock) { ?>

<tr>
    <!-- <td><?php //echo $LocalClock['LocalClock']['id']; ?></td> -->
    <td><?php echo $this->Html->link($LocalClock['LocalClock']['id'], array('controller'=>'localClocks', 
    'action'=>'view', $LocalClock['LocalClock']['id'])); ?></td> 

    <td><?php echo $LocalClock['LocalClock']['name']; ?></td>

<td><input type="button" class="viewButton" value="View" onclick="location.href='<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller' => 'localClocks', 'action' => 'view', $LocalClock['LocalClock']['id'])); ?>';"/>
<input type="button" class="editButton" value="Edit" onclick="location.href='<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller' => 'localClocks', 'action' => 'edit', $LocalClock['LocalClock']['id'])); ?>';"/>
    </td>
</tr>

<?php } ?>

</tbody>
</table>
```

I need help with switching the button onclick events to opening the dialog box and have the dialog box display the respective View pages.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is how I was able to accomplish this.  I hope it helps others.

First add blank div's into the index page with an id.

```
<div id="view_dialog"></div>
```

Then, using jQuery, create a function to create a dialog out of that div.

```
    <script>
$(function()
{
    var $dialog = $("#view_dialog").dialog(
        {
            autoOpen: false,
            title: 'View Local Clock',
            height: 200,
            width: 1200,
            resizable: true,
            modal: true,
            buttons:
            {
                "Ok": function()
                {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
    $(".view_dialog").click(function()
    {
        $dialog.load($(this).attr('href'), function ()
                {
                    $dialog.dialog('open');
                });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

And, lastly, create the button/link.

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('View', array('action' => 'view', $LocalClock['LocalClock']['id']), array('class' => 'view_dialog')); ?>
```

This code allowed me to have a dialog box open when I clicked on the view link that shows the specific info for that item in the dialog box.